# Return value optimization in VC2008

Tags: c++, optimization, visual-c++-2008, return-value-optimization

Is there other technique like RVO (return value optimization) or NRVO (named return value optimization) that can be use with VC2008?

Comment: just to know, so that I don't write code that cannot be optimized by my compiler provided there is a posibility

Comment: don't bother, write code without such optimizations, spend that time thinking about algorithms instead. If one particular function would became a bottleneck, only then optimize it (but do profiling to check that it is an optimization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler_optimization#Optimization_techniques_2) may help you.

But typically it's the compiler who does such kind of optimization, not you.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't worry too much about those optimisations if I were you. Apart from anything else, they are not portable.

If you are worried about writing efficient C++ code, the number one rule is to avoid copying altogether. Make sure you use reference in all places where they are possible, but don't try to use them where they are not. After, all sometimes you actually need a new value - as the return value for implementations of operator+(), for example.

Comment: More Effective C++ has an item on RVO ..so thought it would be good to know these things